# Proofs problem with bijection

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $f : A \rightarrow B$. Prove that if $X \subseteq A, Y \subseteq B$, and $f$ is a bijection, then $f(X) = Y$ if and only if $f^{-1}(Y) = X$.

Comment: Try to show that $ff^{-1}(S)=S$ and $f^{-1}f(S)=S$ when $f$ is bijective. One of the inclusions is easier.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

How do you prove two sets are equal? Prove they're subsets of each other.

Hints for the forward direction:

If we assume $f(X) = Y$, then the inclusion $X \subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$ is true by assumption.

To prove $f^{-1}(Y) \subseteq X$, use proof by contradiction. Suppose there exists $x \in f^{-1}(Y)$ such that $x \notin X$. Show that this contradicts the bijectivity of $f$.

If you can prove the forward direction, the reverse implication is proved similarly.